# How to make gui in c#

Tags: c#, user-interface

Ive tried labels but it isn't a hitbox and there hard to use.
so im wondering if there is a class or click event.

--LabelCode--

```
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //insert code here
    }
```

Comment: is this winform application? please Tag the question correctly.

Comment: "its visual C# 2012" - so it could be WinForms, WPF, HTML + JS, ASP.NET... and on and on. What kind of GUI are you trying to build?

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:** You need to `Subscribe` to the `Label Click` event before writing the `Event Handler`

Try This:

```
label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(label1_Click);
```

The above statement `Registers/Subscribes` to the `Label Click` event using `label1_Click` handler so that `label1_Click` is notified whenever there is a `Click event` raised on the `Label`

Complete Code looks like :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(label1_Click);
        }   

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // your code here
        }
     }
```

**Method 2:**  you can simplify the above method by simply attaching Event Hadler as below:

```
label1.Click+=label1_Click;
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // your code here
        }
```

Complete Code looks like :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Click += label1_Click;
        }   

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // your code here
        }
     }
```

**Method 3:** you can use Lambda Expression to write Event Handler as below:

```
label1.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                //your code here
            };
```

complete code looks like

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                 label1.Click += (s, e) =>
                {
                    //your code here
                };
            }   

         }
```

**Method 4:**  you can use anonymous methods to write the event handler

```
this.label1.Click += delegate(object o, EventArgs e)
            {
               //your code here
            };
```

Complete Code looks like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public Form1()
                {
                InitializeComponent();
                label1.Click += delegate(object o, EventArgs e)
                {
                   //your code here
                };


             }
```

Comment: awesome but is other ways of doing it??

Comment: you can use lambda expression to write event hanlders see my edited answer.

Comment: @MahchinLizard : i have edited my answer with 4 methods please let me know still if you want anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have comment that you are using "visual C# 2012", simply you can add click event for label by double click on a label when you are in design mode. it will create event handler ad subscribe to your label control